# AWS: what is the most secure way to combine CKM policies and IAM policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

What I want to do is attach an EC2 instance to an IAM group and give that group access to keys for an S3 bucket in CKMs.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: By CKM, you presumably mean CMK. You can't attach EC2 instances to IAM groups. When you create a CMK, you define a policy that dictates who can manage and/or use the CMK. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#key_permissions

Comment: So what about this? : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "so what about this?" You can configure the CMK policy to enable you to use IAM policies to give IAM users and roles in the account access to the CMK. The latter, IAM roles, is typically how you would confer these rights to an EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes it very clear. Appreciate it.

Comment: Great. I'll provide a summary as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a [Customer Master Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#master_keys) (CMK), you define a [key policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#key_permissions) that dictates who can manage and/or use the CMK. Specifically, you can configure the key policy to enable access to the CMK from IAM users and IAM roles in the account. The latter, IAM roles, is what you would use to confer these rights to an EC2 instance.